# Calling jQuery UI constructors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am building a survey tool that will have different layouts and 'inquisitorial' processes depending on the part and actual question that the user is responding too. I am building this in Coldfusion and I am using jQuery UI elements to present questions however this will lead to ui elements embedded in ui elements.

The order in which the UI elements are constructed or triggered is going to be the reverse order that they are presented in the html, so the innermost element has to be triggered first. There is a master page that has the logic that looks up the database for the question information and the specific page layout to use, which is then `<cfinclude'd`, this layout page may have say tabular UI elements

My solution to this has been to declare an array of UI html node names (DIV tags) along with the UI construction method. Each included element then "pushes" it's UI information into this array.

```
var inst_triggers = new Array()
inst_triggers.push("#accordion@@accordion()")
```

finally when everything is assembled I need to trigger these UI elements, so in the master page I do the following.

```
$(function() {
    var it = inst_triggers.reverse();
    var it_len = it.length;

    for (e=0;e<it_len;e++){
        var trig_parts = it[e].split('@@');
    //do the jQuery UI element trigger here
    var eval_str = '$("'+trig_parts[0]+'").'+trig_parts[1];
    eval(eval_str);
    }

});
```

As we know "eval() " is evil so I need an alternative to trigger or construct these page elements
Something like `jQuery.uistuff.method('accordion')`, but I cannot see this in the documentation (or at least I have not understood what I have read which is more likely)

Any suggestions, pointers further reading or references would be GREATLY appreciated.

Regards thanks to the collective neural network in advance !

Gus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the approach that you have posted, I'm not sure why you are using the @@ and splitting on it in order to determine your components. You could just as easily push an object to the "inst_triggers" array:

```
var inst_triggers = [];
inst_triggers.push({selector:"#accordion", method: "accordion"});

$(function() {
    var it = inst_triggers,
        it_len = it.length;

    it.reverse()

    for ( e=0; e < it_len; e++ ) {
        $(it[e].selector)[it[e].method]();
    }
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/uBpk5/

Comment: Hi bstakes and thanks for your time.
I have used you code but I got an error flagged in firebug 
'$(it[e].selector)[it[e].method]() is not a function'

I guess what I was looking for was two steps.

Comment: 1. get a reference to the ui object then 
2. used a 'generic' reference to a method call such as object.method('accordion()')

I am trying to think like the dom tree traversal stuff node.attr('id') 
Gus

Comment: Well, of course its not a method...I spelled accordion wrong. editing now.

Comment: Thanks bstakes as I have had a chance to return to this aspect of my project, refined what was happening and I have found this to be the most flexible approach. So I have avoided the evil eval !!!

Many thanks for the collective wisdom of Stackoverflow and one day like grasshopper I might get to leave temple !!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [Developer's Guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Developer_Guide#jQuery.fn) for jQuery UI, in particular the `jQuery.fn` section. Basically, all the jQuery widgets takes a namespace under `jQuery.fn`. So, that means

```
$('#accordion').accordion(options);
```

is equivalent to

```
$.fn['accordion'].call($('#accordion'), options);
```

and

```
$.fn['accordion'].apply($('#accordion'), [options]);
```

I am not sure my solution is any better than bstakes's, but it is an alternative. The bottom line is, avoid using the evil `eval()`s.

Comment: Thanks for your response WIlliam I have just come back into the office from the weekend and I think you have pointed tome to where I need to go, I will of course post the outcome !
  Gus

Comment: Hi William I am not sure how I would pass an object into this when constructing the UI widget. Does this work `$.fn['accordion'].arg({autoHeight:false}).apply($('#accordion'))`

Comment: You can pass in the arguments as a list to the `.apply()`, as pass in each arguments using `.call()`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks William, this needs to go into my own sort of Knowledge base. I really appreciate your time

Gus